# Restoring bookmarked Shiny app when using insertUI and Shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to restore the state of an app that includes a `selectizeInput()` generated with `renderUI()` inside a Shiny module. Because the number of choices is large (in my real app), I'm using server-side selectize--which I think is the main stumbling block.

Why doesn't the following example app restore the selections for the `ns("choices")` input after making selections, bookmarking, and then copying and pasting into new browser tab?

```r
library(shiny)
choices <- c("a", "b", "c")

insert_choices_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    id = ns("main"),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("select"), label = "Select", choices = c("no", "yes")),
    uiOutput(ns("ui1"))
  )
}

insert_choices_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      output$ui1 <- renderUI({
        req(input$select)
        if (input$select == "yes") {
          tags$div(selectizeInput(
            inputId = ns("choices"),
            label = "Choices",
            choices = NULL,
            multiple = TRUE
          ))
        }
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$select, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = FALSE,  {
        updateSelectizeInput(
          session,
          inputId = "choices",
          choices = choices,
          server = TRUE
        )
      })
    })
}

ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    id = "main",
    actionButton("addButton", "Add Options"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$addButton, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    insertUI(selector = "#main", ui = {
      insert_choices_ui(paste0("id", input$addButton))
    })
    insert_choices_server(id  = paste0("id", input$addButton))
  })
  
  onRestore(function(state) {
    for (i in seq_len(input$addButton)) {
      insertUI("#main", ui = insert_choices_ui(id = paste0("id", i)))
      
      insert_choices_server(id = paste0("id", i))
    }
  })
  
  onRestored(function(state) {
    if (!is.null(state$input$addButton) && state$input$addButton > 0) {
      for (i in seq_len(input$addButton)) {
        updateSelectizeInput(
          session,
          paste0("id", i, "-choices"),
          choices = choices,
          selected = state$input[[paste0("id", i, "-choices")]],
          server = TRUE
        )
      }
    }
  })
}

enableBookmarking(store = "server")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue here is that your call to `insert_choices_server` is getting triggered *after* `onRestored` sets the value and you're running this part of your code, which de-selects what your bookmark has selected:

```r
      observeEvent(input$select, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = FALSE,  {
        updateSelectizeInput(
          session,
          inputId = "choices",
          choices = choices,
          server = TRUE
        )
      })
```

Remove those lines and change your `renderUI` function to pass in the choices:

```
      output$ui1 <- renderUI({
        req(input$select)
        if (input$select == "yes") {
          tags$div(selectizeInput(
            inputId = ns("choices"),
            label = "Choices",
            choices = choices,
            multiple = TRUE
          ))
        }
      })
```

(omitted the rest of the code as it is unchanged)

Comment: But I think your change to `renderUI` uses client-side selectize. I want to use server-side selectize to eliminate the lag that is introduced when `choices` is extremely large. See [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html). Although, I think your assessment of the problem might be correct: I'm calling `insert_choices_server()` inside `onRestore` (which is run prior to `onRestored`), but the `updateSelectizeInput` you include in your answer is perhaps not triggered until *after* `onRestored` is finished running.

Comment: Is there a way to make `observeEvent` conditional on whether a bookmark is being restored? That might be the key.

Comment: If that's what you want, then your issue seems to be unrelated to the bookmarking. If you look at [this comment](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1963#issuecomment-369390234) you can see that using `renderUI` then `updateSelectizeInput` will prevent you from using server-side selectize. If you move the code from a call to `rednerUI` to a `selectInput` in the UI function, that should fix your issue.

Comment: @GiovanniColitti I can't comment below, but the issue is using `server-side selectize` and  `renderUI` -- the bookmarking is unrelated to the issues you're having. If you stop using renderUI, bookmarking and server-side selectize will just work.

Comment: But I want to be able to conditionally show / hide the `choices` input based on the `select` input. I know that if I remove `renderUI` or remove server-side selectize, things work. The difficulty is getting the different desired features to work together. These different features are: bookmarking, server-side selectize, shiny modules, and conditional display of inputs based on other inputs.

Comment: Also, bookmarking doesn't 'just work' when I move the `ns("choices")` input from inside `insert_choices_server` to `insert_choices_ui` and remove the `renderUI` and `uiOutput` code.